# Run a function when any other class function is called

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a es6 class with more then 100 functions.
I added a new function which I have to run each time any other function is called.
I found a lot of solutions but no one solved my problem...
I know I can add this call to each function but then I'll end with code repeat and a lot of work for all the functions.
That is that I've done so far:

```
return class Test {
    constructor () {}

    addedFN() {
         console.log('FN');
    }

    A() {
        this.addedFN();
        console.log('A');
    }

    B() {
        this.addedFN();
        console.log('B');
    }

    C() {
        this.addedFN();
        console.log('C');
    }
    ...
}
```

As we can see in this approach I have a lot of code duplication which I want to avoid...
Also, the solution to call the new function first and then inside to call the next function won't work, because all the functions are used in a lot of places in the application.
I tried also to run the following code in the constructor, but that is a bad solution as my class is called a lot of times and then this code will run each time:

```
for(const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Test.prototype)) {
 const old = Test.prototype[key];
 Test.prototype[key] = function(...args) {
   addedFN(...args);
   old.call(this, ...args);
 };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't run that in the constructor, run that after the class declaration

Also, that solution will result in too much recursion, since it will also apply to `addedFn`, which will call `addedFn`, which will call `addedFn` ... etc, until your browser throws a "too much recursion" error

So you also don't want to apply it to the `addedFn`

In the code below, I also don't apply it to `constructor` ... however, even when I do, it doesn't call `addedFn` when the object is constructed, so, to make it more clear, I explicitly don't touch the constructor

```js
class Test {
  constructor(y) {
    this.y = y
  }
  fun1(x) {
    console.log('I am fun1', x, this.y);
  }
  fun2() {
    console.log('I am fun2');
  }
  addedFn(...x) {
    console.log('added function', ...x);
  }
}
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Test.prototype).forEach(f => {
  if (f !== 'constructor' && f !== 'addedFn' && typeof Test.prototype[f] === 'function') {
    const old = Test.prototype[f];
    Test.prototype[f] = function(...args) {
      this.addedFn(...args);
      return old.apply(this, args);
    }
  }
})
let c = new Test('works');
c.fun1(1,2,3)
```

Note: you should also test if `Test.prototype[f]` is a function - unless your class ONLY has functions

Answer (score 2):

This might be a good use for a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to transparently change your object without actually changing the object, just wrapping it in a proxy.

A [`get` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get) can check if you are accessing a method and then dynamically wrap it into a proxy with an [`apply` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/apply).

```js
class Test {
    A() { console.log('A'); }
    B() { console.log('B'); }
    C() { console.log('C'); }
    get X() { return 1; }
    Y = 2;
}

function addedFN() { console.log('FN'); }

const loggingHandler = {
  apply() {
    addedFN();
    return Reflect.apply(...arguments);
  }
};

const wrapMethods = {
  get() {
    const result = Reflect.get(...arguments);
    if (typeof result === "function")
      return new Proxy(result, loggingHandler);
    return result;
  }
};

const test = new Test();
const foo = new Proxy(test, wrapMethods);

foo.A();
foo.B();
foo.C();
console.log(foo.X);
console.log(foo.Y);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

The approach can be generalised to accept different possible modifiers to methods and cache them in a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)

```js
class Test {
    A() { console.log('A'); }
    B() { console.log('B'); }
    C() { console.log('C'); }
    get X() { return 1; }
    Y = 2;
}

function addedFN() { console.log('FN'); }

const noop = () => {};
const wrapFunction = ({before = noop, after = noop}) => ({
  apply() {
    before();
    const result = Reflect.apply(...arguments);
    after();
    return result;
  }
});

const wrapMethods = handler => ({
  _cache: new WeakMap(),
  get() {
    const result = Reflect.get(...arguments);
    if (typeof result === "function") {
      if (!this._cache.has(result))
        this._cache.set(result, new Proxy(result, handler));
        
      return this._cache.get(result);
    }
    
    return result;
  }
});

const loggingHandler = wrapFunction({before: addedFN});

const test = new Test();
const foo = new Proxy(test, wrapMethods(loggingHandler));

foo.A();
foo.B();
foo.C();
console.log(foo.X);
console.log(foo.Y);
```

Comment: ... nice, lean, elegant.